# Karndean over underlay

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring, vinyl, underlayment

I'm laying Karndean Korlok planks. I've taken out the engineered wood floor I'm replacing. I have a Tredaire underlay below over the concrete, that for acoustic insulation. It's 6mm thick rubber. Do I really need to remove it before I lay the Karndean? Their instructions say their flooring needs no underlay, but does need a solid floor. My Karndean samples aren't moving on top of it, and pulling it out it feels like a waste of good materials.

Comment: I have not encountered the Karndean brand of flooring, but 6MM sounds like a pretty thick underlay for a floating floor, unless it is very dense. I would do as the manufacturer recommended.

Comment: "Needs no underlay" is not the same thing as "must not have any underlay" so probably a call or email to the manufacturer's customer support is in order to clarify their intent. A firm solid rubber layer over concrete is still "solid" as I see it, but I'm unfamiliar with the specific products. A squishy foam rubber layer might be a problem.

Comment: Thanks @RMDman and @Ecnerwal!